# Drop down menu drop vertically on the link

Tags: html, css

This must be basic to some but not to all new CSS members. Quick one how do I have the drop down menu drop on the same link not as in line? I want it to drop vertically on the same place not to extend in line. Any one?

```css
.nav-container {
      float: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
     
     
    }

    .navigation-menu {
      padding:  0;
      float: center;
      clear: both;
      font-size: 12px

      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navigation-menu > li {
       margin-right: 3px;
        margin: 100px auto;
       
        line-height:20px;
        max-width:860px;
        display: inline;
     }

    .navigation-menu li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .navigation-menu li a {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      display:inline-block;
      
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color: #696969;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }

.navigation-menu li.active a {
      background-color: purple;
      color:#fff;
      }
    .navigation-menu li ul {
      display: none;
      
    }
    .navigation-menu ul li a{
      padding:10px 20px;
    }

    #main {
      clear: left;
    }

    .navigation-menu li:hover ul {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;  
      padding:5px;
      
    }

    .navigation-menu li ul li a:hover{
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
     display: block;
    }


    .navigation-menu li a:hover{
      background-color:black;
      color: white;
 
   }
   .navigation-menu li a:active {
    background-color: purple;
    color:#fff;
}

.navigation-menuul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="navigation-menu">
      <li><a href='#' >Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href='#' >C2B Payments</a> </li>
          <li><a href='#' >C2B SMS</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> C2B SMS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Send SMS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Campaign SMS</a></li>
        </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code `.navigation-menu li { position: relative; }` and also `.navigation-menu li ul { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; }` to get the result of aligned dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Add to this css in your file

```
.navigation-menu li:hover ul {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}


.navigation-menu > li {
    position: relative;
}
```

```css
.nav-container {
      float: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
     
     
    }
.navigation-menu li:hover ul {
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}


.navigation-menu > li {
position: relative;
}
    .navigation-menu {
      padding:  0;
      float: center;
      clear: both;
      font-size: 12px

      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navigation-menu > li {
       margin-right: 3px;
        margin: 100px auto;
       
        line-height:20px;
        max-width:860px;
        display: inline;
     }

    .navigation-menu li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .navigation-menu li a {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      display:inline-block;
      
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color: #696969;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }

.navigation-menu li.active a {
      background-color: purple;
      color:#fff;
      }
    .navigation-menu li ul {
      display: none;
      
    }
    .navigation-menu ul li a{
      padding:10px 20px;
    }

    #main {
      clear: left;
    }

    .navigation-menu li:hover ul {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;  
      padding:5px;
      
    }

    .navigation-menu li ul li a:hover{
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
     display: block;
    }


    .navigation-menu li a:hover{
      background-color:black;
      color: white;
 
   }
   .navigation-menu li a:active {
    background-color: purple;
    color:#fff;
}

.navigation-menuul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="navigation-menu">
      <li><a href='#' >Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href='#' >C2B Payments</a> </li>
          <li><a href='#' >C2B SMS</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> C2B SMS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Send SMS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Campaign SMS</a></li>
        </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-container {
      float: center;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      margin-bottom: 11px;
     
     
    }

    .navigation-menu {
      padding:  0;
      float: center;
      clear: both;
      font-size: 12px

      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .navigation-menu > li {
       margin-right: 3px;
        margin: 100px auto;
       
        line-height:20px;
        max-width:860px;
        display: inline;
     }

    .navigation-menu li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .navigation-menu li a {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      display:inline-block;
      
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color: #696969;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }

.navigation-menu li.active a {
      background-color: purple;
      color:#fff;
      }
    .navigation-menu li ul {
      display: none;
     position: relative;
     top: 50px;
     left: 215px;
      
    }
    .navigation-menu ul li a{
      padding:10px 20px;
    }

    #main {
      clear: left;
    }

    .navigation-menu li:hover ul {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;  
      padding:5px;
      
    }

    .navigation-menu li ul li a:hover{
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
     display: block;
    }


    .navigation-menu li a:hover{
      background-color:black;
      color: white;
 
   }
   .navigation-menu li a:active {
    background-color: purple;
    color:#fff;
}

.navigation-menuul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul class="navigation-menu">
      <li><a href='#' >Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href='#' >C2B Payments</a> </li>
          <li><a href='#' >C2B SMS</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> C2B SMS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Send SMS</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"> Campaign SMS</a></li>
        </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```